# I am learning Java and the following program only accepts an answer of 0

Tags: java, variables

I have the following code to ask a multiplication problem and asks the user for the answer, then checks the answer to see if it is correct.

I can get it working to the point where it checks the answer. It only accepts 0 and that is because for some reason I initialized the answer as 0.

If I change it to num1 * num2 in the code, it won't accept it. I was looking for assistance or resources to help me find the answer, I don't just want someone to give me the answer.  Thanks in advance.

```
//Multiply.java -- prints multiplication questions for user to answer

import java.util.Random; // import Random
import java.util.Scanner; // import Scanner

public class Test 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {               
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );

        int guess; // the user's guess to the question

        createQuestion(); // display the first question to the user

        System.out.println( "Enter your answer (-1 to exit):" ); // asks the question
        guess = input.nextInt(); // accepts the users answer

        while ( guess != -1 ) // if guess is not -1
        { // start while
            checkResponse( guess ); // calls checkResponse to check guess

            System.out.println( "Enter your answer (-1 to exit):" ); // prompts user for answer
            guess = input.nextInt(); // the users answer that is entered
        } // end while  
    } // end main

    private static void createQuestion() 
    { // start createQuestion
        Random randomNumbers = new Random();

        // get two random numbers between 0 and 9
        int num1 = randomNumbers.nextInt( 10 );
        int num2 = randomNumbers.nextInt( 10 );

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        int answer = (num1 * num2); // answer to the question
        System.out.printf( "How much is %d times %d?\n", // prompts for the answer
                num1, num2 );
    } // end createQuestion

    private static void checkResponse(int guess) 
    { // start checkResponse
        int answer = 0; /* this is where I have the problem if I change 0 
         * to (num1 * num2) it can't resolve to a variable. I am trying to bring 
         * down the answer variable from createQuestion */

        if ( guess != answer ) // if the users answer is not correct
            System.out.println( "No. Please try again." );
        else
        { // start else
            System.out.println( "Very Good!" ); // if the users answer is correct
            createQuestion();
        } // end else
    } // end checkResponse
} // end class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare `guess` and `answer` as attributes of **`Test`**.

```
public class Test 
{
     private static int guess;
     private static int answer;
     // ...
}
```

This way, you will be able to use them in both `createQuestion()` & `checkResponse()`.
The *correct (and latest) values* will be accessible from both functions.

Comment: Thanks so much. I did that and removed the other declarations from the rest of the code. One of them was still giving me a hard time and it ended up being an issue with Eclipse. It was not changing things for me, I had to enter the same code that was not working in a new line right above it. As soon as I did, and I removed the bad line, it worked for me.  Thanks so much for the help, Even with this simple question, I learned so much!

Comment: @JamesWoodSr Glad to know that I managed to help you with some of your doubts, and good luck in your conquest of Java :)

Answer (score 0):

Declare "answer" outside of your method checkResponse and put it as member of the Test class. Then, assign the value of it from your createQuestion method.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use a variable outside of its method. You should declare variables outside of your method.